# Using a query in an update

Tags: oracle, update

I have a query which generates a result set (key, a, b).

I want to use an update statement where, for each entry in a table with Tkey = key, set ColA = a, ColB = b.

How would I do this?

Right now I'm trying:

```
UPDATE table1
set ColA = a,
ColB = b
where TKey in (select TKey, a, b from ...)
```

but a and b can't reference the where clause, right? So how can I do this?

Comment: Let me clear on it. You are updating the COLA and COLB with the value of another table which has got same number of columns as table1. Am i right?

Comment: No, I'm producing a and b as a result of a fairly complex query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One syntax that can be used is the following. Instead of the syntax that is not working:

```
update table1
set cola = a,
    colb = b
where tkey in  
    (select u.tkey, a, b
     from ... u ...         -- some tables here, one of them is "u"
    ) ;
```

This will do what is wanted (note that the `where` should be there, otherwise all the rows of `table1` will be updated, but with `NULL` values for those that there is no matching `tkey` in the subquery):

```
update table1 t
set (cola, colb) = 
    (select a, b
     from ... u ...         -- some tables here, one of them is "u"
     where u.tkey = t.tkey
    ) 
where exists
    (select *               -- whatever
     from ... u ...         -- nothing changed here
     where u.tkey = t.tkey
    ) ;
```

While the above has some code duplicated, there is another option that uses an updateable view/subquery and has no duplication:

```
update 
  (select t.cola, t.colb, 
          u.a as new_a, u.b as new_b
   from table1 t 
     join ... u ...                  -- your subquery FROM clause here
        on u.tkey = t.tkey
  ) upd
set (cola, colb) = (new_a, new_b) ;
-- or the common syntax    
-- set cola = new_a,
--     colb = new_b ;
```

And a third option is using `MERGE`, as in [BriteSponge's answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/126297/using-a-query-in-an-update/126361#126361) which is prefectly good.

Tested in **[SQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/5c49d/7)**.

Answer (score 2):

I'm a big fan of MERGE.
You can try the following;

```
MERGE INTO table1 main
USING ( SELECT TKey, a, b
          FROM table2 ) subsel
ON (main.TKey = subsel.TKey) 
WHEN MATCHED THEN
UPDATE SET main.ColA = subsel.a,
          main.ColB = subsel.b
```

Here's a quick example;

```
SQL> SELECT * FROM maintab;

TKEY                 COLA                 COLB
-------------------- -------------------- --------------------
rec1
rec2
rec3

SQL> SELECT * FROM updtable;

TKEY                 A                    B
-------------------- -------------------- --------------------
rec1                 123                  456
rec2                 789                  321
rec3                 654                  987

SQL> l
  1  MERGE INTO maintab main
  2  USING ( SELECT TKey, a, b
  3            FROM updtable ) subsel
  4  ON (main.TKey = subsel.TKey)
  5  WHEN MATCHED THEN
  6  UPDATE SET main.ColA = subsel.a,
  7*            main.ColB = subsel.b
SQL> /

3 rows merged.

SQL> SELECT * FROM maintab;

TKEY                 COLA                 COLB
-------------------- -------------------- --------------------
rec1                 123                  456
rec2                 789                  321
rec3                 654                  987
```